# Installing packages but cant use them

Tags: apt, 18.04

I am a newbie to Ubuntu, trying to install some packages in Ubuntu 18.04

I have installed the following packages :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt install protobuf-c-compiler
```

But when I run the following command, I get an error `command not found`.

```bash
protobuf{-c,}-compiler python python-devlibgoogle-perftools-dev
```

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: did you do an update before? it could help a little and here is the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: `protobuf-c-compiler` is `protoc-c` in the binaries it uses - the actual *command* is not the name of the package itself.  Have you actually tested this commands?

Comment: Protocol Buffers C is just a compiler. It could be invoked using `protoc-c` and need some input file. Can you please [edit] your question and elaborate what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I see the command is not suppose to be used like that. Thank you for your responses, also I am trying to install Gem5 by copying the commands from a manual ( don't actually understand a thing yet )

Comment: @skyDfy Are you still facing the issue? Please [edit] your question and include the manual/link to the manual.

Comment: @Kulfy The issue is resolved as I was not using the command properly. Also the "manual" I am following is provided for assignment and not available online. Thank you for the responses :D